jenkins artifact - how to set the base prefix to use NODE_NAME from environment list variable
we use artifact manager plugin in jenkins to pull out the build logs from all jenkins job, but to make the folder inside the S3 bucket  being uniq, we need to set the folder as server name/node-name where the logs come from. anyone know how to set the base prefix as ${NODE_NAME} ?
have tried to set this on the manage jenkins - AWS seems doesnt work

the value of foler name can't passing as server-name/node-name in S3 bucket


artifact-manager-s3 doesn't expand variables in its fields. Is your jenkins server name dynamic? I would imagine most configurations have it as static and it can be just hardcoded into the plugin config. If you are using configuration-as-code you can have parameterized there.
